# getimagesize returns null with some images

Tags: php, getimagesize

I have php code to store an image that looks like this...

```
        $tempFile = $_FILES['postImageUpload']['tmp_name'];

        list($width,$height, $type)=getimagesize($tempFile);

        if ($type == 1){
            $src = imagecreatefromgif($tempFile);
        }
        elseif ($type == 2){
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($tempFile);
        }
        elseif ($type == 3){
            $src = imagecreatefrompng($tempFile);
        }
        else{
            $src = imagecreatefromwbmp($tempFile);
        }
```

It works 95% of the time regardless of filetype and size (within reason I'm sure).  But sometimes I see errors like...

**Warning**:  imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error:  in **/Applications/myAppPath/myPhpFile.php** on line **87**

**Warning**:  imagecreatefromjpeg(): '/Applications/myAppPath/tmp/php/phpj390wL' is not a valid JPEG file in **/Applications/MAMP/ppStage/includes/postImageUpload.php** on line **87**

The reason for this is that sometimes, getimagesize returns null.  This is an example of an image that looks perfectly normal but will return null from imagecreatefromjpeg()...

http://i1.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article7181872.ece/ALTERNATES/s615/A-GP-writing-a-prescription.jpg

I'm completely lost of why this might be the case since it seems like a perfectly acceptable jpg.  Really appreciate any thoughts at all on what might be going wrong here!

Comment: Well, did you read the errors? 'cuz one says `Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): '/Applications/myAppPath/tmp/php/phpj390wL' is not a valid JPEG file`